# how to add namespace.expect for parameters passed in url as argument

Tags: swagger-ui, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I have written below `Resource` Class:

```
@clinic_api_ns.route("/patient/profile")
class PatientProfile(Resource):
    def get(self):
        patient = request.args.get(patient)
        relative = request.args.get(relative)
        relationType = request.args.get(relationType)
        contactNumber = request.args.get(contactNumber)
        townCity = request.args.get(townCity)
        return controller.get_patient_profile(patient, relative, relationType, contactNumber, townCity)
```

so that to get patient profile , I can use passed parameters through URL such as `http://ip.address/api/clinic/patient/profile?patient=<patientName>&relative=<relativeName>&relationType=<relation>`

but this throws error in swagger documentation and even if I tried adding `@_api_ns.expect(patient_profile, validate=True)`

where `patient_profile` is

```
class PatientProfile(object):
    profile = clinic_api_ns.model("profile", {
        "patient": fields.String(required=True, description="name of the patient."),
        "relative": fields.String(required=True, description="name of parent or husband."),
        "relation": fields.String(required=True, description="type of relation with patient."),
        "contactnumber": fields.String(required=True, description="contact number of the patient."),
        "townCity": fields.String(required=True, description="town or city the patient belongs to."),        
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parser to solve this.

```
parser = api.parser()
parser.add_argument('param', type=int, help='Some param', location='path') # "location='path'" means look only in the querystring


@api.expect(parser)
```